# Finding The Distribution Of the Sum Of Two i.i.d Random Variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

I need to see the computation steps to get from the question to the answer. Given below is the question and its corresponding answer at the bottom of the image.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S = 2$ when $X_1 = X_2 = 1$. $P(X_1 = 1 \text{ and } X_2 = 1) = P(X_1 = 1)P(X_2=1)$ since $X_1, X_2$ are independent. So $P(S = 2) = p_1^2$.

$S = 3$ when $X_1 = 1$ and $X_2 = 2$ or when $X_1 = 2$ and $X_2 = 1$. Each of those scenarios happen with probability $p_1p_2$

$S=4$ when $X_1 = 1$, $X_2 = 3$, the other way around (each with way with prob $p_1p_3$), or they're both $2$, with prob $p_2^2$.

In general, you're applying the discrete convolution formula. The intuition is to look at all the ways the two variables can sum up to $k$ and add up the probabilities for each of the ways.

Comment: I see. So then can I view it like this? \n

Set of combinations for each random variable \n
A = { (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3) } \n

Set of sums of each of the combinations \n
B = { 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6 } \n

set of distinct values of sum of each combination \n
C = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 } \n

Iterate on C to find number of occurrences of each c_i in B as a proportion of the size of B?

Comment: I made some corrections to my comment above. I was eventually able to generalize and create a method for finding the coefficients and exponents of a pgf, given a set of possible values and their corresponding probabilities. Thank you again for showing me those in-between steps! <3